# How can I checkout a github commit from outside a branch

Tags: git, github

To be specific, my goal is to have access to this specific commit
https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/commit/73afde67830bb6e49388d0e3a135e945fdbbfc4a

The issue is that the commit is outside a specific branch. So I can't just fetch its branch. `git fetch ankidroid 73afde6` (where ankidroid is my local name for this remote)  or `git pull ankidroid 73afde6` fails. If I do `git fetch` the command at least succeed, but the commit `73afde6` is still not known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some hosting sites won't allow you to fetch a commit by its hash ID.  If you are using such a hosting site, you *must* find some *name* that will allow fetching the commit.  Fortunately for you, you are using [github](/questions/tagged/github), which *does* allow fetching by raw hash ID.<sup>1</sup>

The trick is that you *must use the full hash ID*.  That is, run:

```
git fetch ankidroid 73afde67830bb6e49388d0e3a135e945fdbbfc4a
```

The command:

```
git fetch ankidroid 73afde6
```

does not suffice.

(You might want to give the commit a name you can refer to in your local repository, e.g., `git fetch ankidroid 73afde67830bb6e49388d0e3a135e945fdbbfc4a:refs/heads/foo`.  This creates a new branch name `foo` in your local repository, pointing to the fetched commit.  This assumes you do not currently have a branch named `foo`; if so, substitute in some other name.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The new partial clone feature requires this, so it's becoming more common.